# Preventing users from disabling Office addins

Tags: microsoft-office, group-policy, outlook-addin

I would like to prevent non-admin users from disabling an addin we will be deploying company-wide. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Currently the best I can do is to track registry changes and re-enable the addin upon next start of the Office application, however the user can still use the Office application without the addin if he disables the addin( until he restarts the application.)

Answer (score 2):

I think, [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled) is what you are looking for:

For system administrators, Outlook 2013 provides an enhanced level of control over add-ins using group policy. **Group policy will always override user settings and users are prevented from changing add-in settings** for add-ins that have been configured by the group policy "List of Managed Add-ins".

The registry keys and settings are described in the following tables:

Key:

```
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Resiliency\AddinList
```

... and so long

Take a look, HTH

Comment: Thank you, this should help with Outlook. Too bad there seems to be no straightforward way for other apps.